# Set Undo Level by the use of VBA in MS Project 2010

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

How to set Undo Level of MS project 2010 by the help of Visual Basic.

I set by option> Advanced>Undo Level but it's not working properly. 
How to find VB code window for set the undo level in MS project 2010.

Answer (score 1):

The property is `UndoLevels`. For example: `Application.UndoLevels = 10` set the number of undo levels to 10.